# IF and THEN statements on spreadsheets using color

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I am creating spreadsheets with multiple tabs for children to work through. To show they have completed each tab, when they have finished the work correctly I am using the following statements:

```
=IF(A1="5","Well Done!", "")
```

In this scenario, if the child enters the correct answer of '5', they are told it is correct. I would like to do the same thing with color, where they enter red and are told it is correct. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

- add this script to your sheet:

  ```
  function GETHEX(input) { 
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input).getBackgrounds(); }
  ```
- cell **E20**: **`=GETHEX("B20")`**

  [image: 0]
- cell **C20**: **`=IF(E20="#ff0000", "well done", "you failed!")`**
- hide column **E**

  [image: 0]

Comment: That's for that! It definitely looks on the right track, but I cannot get it to work. The imgur pictures are blocked on my network so I will have a look when I get home to see if that helps. When I try, the E20 shows #ffffff and the C20 shows 'you failed'. I am aiming for it to show you win when I change to the correct colour.

Comment: Thanks again for this, it was a lot clearer with the pictures when I tried at home. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working like I wanted. I am aiming for immediate feedback where the red colour gives 'correct' and any other colour gives 'incorrect'. When added the script and ran it, it only seemed to show a difference when I showed and hid the E column. I was also receiving an error message on line 2 of the code. It might be that I need to better understand how scripts work on a Google Sheet, in which case I will do some research into it. Thanks for getting me started.

Answer (score -1):

- **install this add-on:** **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb?utm_source=permalink)**

  ```
  =IF(COUNTBACKGROUNDCOLOR("B3", "K3", C3)=1, "well done!", "game over!")
  ```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

- **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13F6JqBcMKuMpd4kmyBdy6n1li1I6DZz_3cep6i41d0s/edit#gid=0)**